# SQL Server : getting sum of values in "calendar" table without joining

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to get a the sum of `value` from the `calendar_table` to the `main_table` without joining like below?

```
select 
    date, sum(value)
from 
    main_table
inner join 
    calendar_table on start_date <= date and end_date >= date
group by 
    date
```

I am trying to avoid a join like this because `main_table` is a very large table with rows that have very large start and end dates, and it is absolutely killing my performance. And I've already indexed both tables.

Sample desired results:

```
+-----------+-------+
|   date    | total |
+-----------+-------+
| 7-24-2010 |    11 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Sample tables

**calendar_table**:

```
+-----------+-------+
|   date    | value |
+-----------+-------+
| 7-24-2010 |     5 |
| 7-25-2010 |     6 |
| ...       |   ... |
| 7-23-2020 |     2 |
| 7-24-2020 |    10 |
+-----------+-------+
```

**main_table**:

```
+------------+-----------+
| start_date | end_date  |
+------------+-----------+
| 7-24-2010  | 7-25-2010 |
| 8-1-2011   | 8-5-2011  |
+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: how is the "value" column populated int he calendar_table. Is there  a "rule"/"forumla" to construct the value from a date field?. Eg:7-24-2010 has value=5 and 7-25-2010 has value=6

Comment: You could try using a cross-apply vs inner join, though performance will vary.  Looking at the execution plan may help.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph column "value" just exists, it is not calculated.

Comment: @NathanChampion Are you able to provide an example of what cross-apply would roughly look like? Thanks.

Comment: since you are summing up the "value" your query would need to query/join the calendar_date, its unavoidable

Comment: can you share the table structure of the two tables and the indexes which you have created

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph In terms of structure, it is nearly identical to the example. One from with a start and end date and another with a "calendar" style column and a value associated with each date. Indexes were created on date, start_date and end_date.

Comment: Just curious, you say that the main_table is killing your performance. Why do you say that? If you wrote a SQL statement without the SUM, would you be querying the entire table, or using a WHERE clause to filter it down?

Comment: @Jason Hey, sorry for the confusion, I meant the process of joining a large table with large date ranges is killing my performance. If we look at a small example: say I have 5 rows with date ranges of 90 days, that means prior to a group by on date and sum on the "value" column, I've effectively created 90 x 5 = 450 rows from joining

Comment: Just for giggles .. how many rows are in your two tables?

Comment: @Jason 500 million rows, with each row having date ranges of up to 3 years. :(

Comment: Sorry man ... that's for the main table I assume? Is the calendar table similar? I was just setting up a test case on my local server with 1M random rows and wanted to experiment is all.

Comment: @Jason Calendar table is just a table with a date column that has about 10 years worth of days stored, like in the example. Each row is a day starting from roughly 2010 somewhere going up to 2020, and with each date it has a respective value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218558/discussion-between-jason-and-simon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the sum in the calendar table.  So, I would recommend an "incremental" approach.  This starts by unpivoting the data and putting the value as an increment and decrement in the results:

```
select c.date, c.value as inc
from main_table m join
     calendar_table t
     on m.start_date = c.date
union all
select dateadd(day, 1, c.date), - c.value as inc
from main_table m join
     calendar_table t
     on m.end_date = c.date;
```

The final step is to aggregate and do a cumulative sum:

```
select date, sum(inc) as value_on_date,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by date) as net_value
from ((select c.date, c.value as inc
       from main_table m join
            calendar_table t
            on m.start_date = c.date
      ) union all
      (select dateadd(day, 1, c.date), - c.value as inc
       from main_table m join
            calendar_table t
            on m.end_date = c.date
      )
     ) c
group by date
order by date;
```

This is processing two rows of data for each row in the master table.  Assuming that your time spans are longer than two days typically for each master row, the resulting data processed should be much smaller.  And smaller data implies a faster query.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this ... but be aware, it is still technically 'joined' to the main table. If you look at an execution plan, you will see that there is a join operation of some kind going on.

```
select
   date,
   (select sum(value) from calendar_table t where m.start_date <= t.date and m.end_date >= t.date)
from
   main_table m
```

The thing about that query is that the 'main_table' is not grouped as part of the results. You could possibly do that outside the select, but I don't know what you are trying to achieve. If you are grouping just to get the SUM, then perhaps maintaining the 'main_table' in the group is superflous.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cross-apply example to *possibly* work from.

```
select main_table.date
     , CalendarTable.ValueSum
from main_table
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT SUM(value) as ValueSum
    FROM calendar_table
    WHERE start_date <= main_table.date and main_table.end_date >= date
) as CalendarTable
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you must perform a join of some sort in order to get data from more than one table in a query.

You did not provide details if the indexes which are important for performance. I suggest the following indexes to optimize query performance.

For `calendar_table`, make sure you have a unique clustered index (or primary key) on `date`. Alternatively, a unique nonclustered index on `date` with the `value` column included.

A composite index on the `main_table` `start_date` and `end_date` columns may also be beneficial.

Even with optimal indexes, the query will still take some time against a 500M row table (e.g. a couple of minutes) with no additional filter criteria. If you need results in milliseconds, create an indexed view to materialize the join and aggregation results. Be aware the indexed view will add overhead for inserts/deletes on both tables as well as for updates to the `value` column in order to keep the index consistent with the underlying data.

Below is an indexed view DDL example.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_example
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    date, sum(value) AS value, COUNT_BIG(*) AS countbig
from 
    dbo.main_table
inner join 
    dbo.calendar_table on start_date <= date and end_date >= date
group by 
    date;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx ON dbo.vw_example(date);
GO
```

Depending on your SQL Server edition, the optimizer may be able to use the indexed view automatically so your original query can use the view index without changes. Otherwise, query the view directly and specify a `NOEXPAND` hint:

```
SELECT date, value AS total
FROM dbo.vw_example WITH (NOEXPAND);
```

**EDIT:**

With the query improvement @GordonLinoff suggested, a non-clustered index on the `main_table` `end_date` column will help optimize that query.